# Team Foundation Server - Continuous Integration in a complex scene

Tags: tfs, build, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm trying to figure out how to optimize the build process in the company where I work. Here is my scene:

- Team Foundation Server 2010 (Plans to migration to 2013 already started)
- Multiple Team Projects with multiple projects and multiple solutions
- The projects reference each other by "project reference".

Example:
- Team Project A
 - Project A1, A2, A3
 - Solution SA1 contains A1, A2, B2
 - Solution SA2 contains A3, A2, B2

Team Project B
 - Project B1, B2, B3
 - Solution SB1 contains B1, B2, A2
 - Solution SB2 contains B3, B2, A2

Some solutions have 30 projects and take over 10 minutes to build all, and this projects appear several times in many solutions. I was wondering if it's possible to avoid recompiling the same project.

If a check-in occur on SB1 for project B1, I would like to recompile this project only once, and use the output of the last build to get the assemblies of the other projects.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the builds to publish the shared libraries to a NuGet feed, then update your references to pull down the binaries from NuGet rather than trying to recompile them each time.

Comment: Hello, sorry for delay to response, this solution look fine, but in case that the project's references with self through "project reference", if I change to NuGet reference, I need to change in projects too, and in this case, how the developers can work? They need to check-in their changes to get a new NuGet packet with these changes? Or there are another solution for developers?